# What happens when my client acks data worth more than 64K in one shot and Window Scale isn't enabled on my machine?

Tags: networking, tcp

Here is how my topology looks like -

Client -> MiddleBox (Load Balancer) -> Server

On the MiddleBox, I don't have window scaling enabled. Now, at a point ->

MiddleBox -----------> Server (Advertises zero window)

Client --------> Middle Box (Client sends an ACK, say 'Y')

Also, Consider that the previous ack sent by the Client to Middlebox was 'X' such that :

Y -X > 65k

Now, without WS enabled, Middlebox can't advertise a window value larger than 65K to backend server. So in this case, what will happen?? I see a transaction hang.

My Middlebox keeps advertising zero window itself. It doesn't open up its window despite client having acked almost 70K of data in one shot. Is it because of Window Scaling not enabled on my MiddleBox??

It is one of those scenarios that is very difficult to reproduce for me. So, I can't just enable WS and see if it fixes the problem.

TIA - 
Sidharth

Answer (score 0):

It can't happen. The peers have to agree on window scaling as part of the TCP handshake.

Comment: so, transaction will hang in this unless I enable Window Scaling on both client, middlebox & server?

Comment: @sidharthsingh That is not a valid deduction from what I said. Read my answer again, and properly this time. I repeat that the situation you describe is impossible. Neither peer will use window scaling unless both have agreed to it.

Comment: I would think it would be possible for a machine to receive an ack which would effectively revoke more than 64K worth of window if that ack was delayed in transit so it arrived after a large quantity of data was exchanged.  Such a packet should not be regarded as 'illegitimate', but rather as being a packet which was legitimately sent, but whose window advertisement values have been superseded by subsequent transmissions (and should thus be ignored).